# Does not show the login page (django)

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am totally new in django. I tried to make a login form. Whenever I press submit button I get the login/login URL it doesn't exist. This is my method in View.py (where i think the problem happens here [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndtKc.png)) (when I go to the login page it shows me the page correctly but button do something wrong)

```
def login(req):
if req.method=='post':
    username=req.POST['username']
    password=req.POST['password']
    print(username,password)
    user=auth.authenticate(username=username,password=password)
    if user is not None:
        auth.login(req,user)
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return redirect("task:login")
else:
    return render(req, "Login.html")
```

this is in urls.py

```
    app_name='task'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.TaskListView.as_view(), name='all'),
    path('task/<int:pk>/', views.TaskDetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    path('task/update/<int:pk>', views.TaskUpdateView.as_view(), name='task_update'),
    path('task/delete/<int:pk>', views.TaskDeleteView.as_view(), name='task_delete'),
    path("task/create/", views.TaskCreateView.as_view(), name="task_create"),

    path("login/", views.login, name='login'),
    path("logout/", views.logout, name='logout'),

]
```

and this is my HTML

```
  <form action="login" method="post">
              {% csrf_token %}
        <label for="username"><b>Userame</b></label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Username" name="username" required>

        <label for="psw"><b>Password</b></label>
        <input type="password" placeholder="Enter Password" name="password" required>

        <div class="row justify-content-center ">
          <button type="submit" class="signupbtn btn btn-primary" name="btn">Login</button>
        </div>
  </form>
```

this is the urls.py in the main:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('',include('task.urls')),
]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you edit your question to add the whole  `urls.py` file that is at the same level with your `settings.py` file?

Comment: your attribute `action` in `<form>` is `login`, which means if you are on `/login/` page, it will append it to the current page. So it either needs to be `/login` (absolute path starting with `/`) or even better, use `{% url "login" %} there to resolve the correct path from your `urls.py`

Comment: thank you @yedpodtrzitko .it fixes with your first sulution.
for better understanding where should I use the second solution?
{% url "login" %} 
I put it in the form but it returns NoReverseMatch at /login/

Comment: because now, as you edited your post, it says it's `{% url "task:login" %}`.